# Generic type not supported System.Guid

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, guid

I want to guid for type of Id Property but it isn't working.
It's conversion error.
How can I do this?

```
public interface IEntity<TKey>
{
    TKey Id { get; set; }
}
```

inherit EntityBase

```
public abstract class EntityBase<TKey> : IEntity<TKey>
{
    public TKey Id { get; set; }
}
```

inherit IRepository

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity, TKey> where TEntity : EntityBase<TKey>
{
    void Add(TEntity entity);

    void Delete(TKey key);

    void Update(TEntity entity);

    TEntity Find(TKey key);

    TEntity Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> lambda);

    IEnumerable<TEntity> WhereSelect(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> lambda = null);
}
```

inherit IRepository

```
public interface INotificationRepository:IRepository<Notification,Guid>
{     

}
```

Comment: It is helpful to provide the error and where it shows up.

Comment: What's the implementation of Notification? It should inherit from `EntityBase<Guid>`, is it perhaps implementing `IEntity<Guid>` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're trying to implicitly convert between whatever `object` you have used in the class signature of `Notification` and the `Guid` (which is a `struct`) you've specified in the signature of `INotificationRepository`.  You either have to use `Guid` in both places, or in both places use `object` which are the same type or where an implicit conversion exists.

The interface signature of `IRepository` forces this condition.

As long as `Notification` derives from `EntityBase<Guid>` there is no conversion error.

```
public class Notification : EntityBase<Guid>
{

}
```

However a reference type conversion error will appear if you attempt to use a reference type as `TKey` without modifying your definition of `INotificationRepository`

```
public class Notification : EntityBase<object>
{

}
```

> The type 'Notification' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'IRepository'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Notification' to 'EntityBase'.